# Cannot use GET in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, xmlhttprequest

i need a little help with my project. When i use that code for node.js, i don't listen the "GET /teste", just a blank page.

```
var http = require("http").createServer(servidor);
var express = require('express');
var io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var querystring = require('querystring');

var contentTypes = {
    js: 'text/javascript',
    css: 'text/css',
    json: 'application/json',
    png: 'image/png',
    jpg: 'image/png',
    wav: 'audio/wav'
};

var recebido;

function processPost(request, response, callback) {
    // Código boilerplate pra receber a querystring pedido HTTP,
    // convertê-la e formatá-la em uma coleção de pares chave-valor

    var queryData = "";
    if(typeof callback !== 'function') return null;

    request.on('data', function(data) {
        queryData += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        request.post = querystring.parse(queryData);
        callback();
    });
}

function servidor(req, res) {
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    var filePath = '.' + req.url;

    if(req.method == 'POST') {
        // Se o método do pedido for HTTP POST, processa a querystring

        processPost(req, res, function() {
            // Imprime a querystring convertida em chaves-valores
            console.log(req.post);
            // O request.post está disponível para ser usado aqui

            // Retorna a página para o cliente com o cód. HTTP 200 (OK)
            res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end();
        });
    }
    else if (filePath == './' || filePath == './index.html') filePath = './index.html';
    else contentType = contentTypes[req.url.split('.').pop()];
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            } else {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end('Ooops... houve um erro: ' + error.code + ' ..\n');
                res.end();
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': contentType
            });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}


app.get('/teste', function(req, res) {
    res.charset = 'UTF-8'
    res.send(recebido);
});


http.listen(5000, "192.168.0.108", function() {
    var host = http.address().address;
    var port = http.address().port;
    console.log('Exemplo na URL http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SmartHouse</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
    <script src="/font-awesome/font.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script> <!-- chamamos o socket.io que por padrão o socket.io cria a rota http sem precisarmos interferir -->

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Sistema Smart House - Automação Residencial</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->

            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="sala.html"><i class="fa fa-television"></i> Sala</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="cozinha.html"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> Cozinha</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Quartos <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="quarto1.html"> Quarto 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="quarto2.html"> Quarto 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Alarme</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Quarto 1 <small>Geral</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Quarto 1
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h1><center>Quarto 1 - Lampada</center></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="QTD1LED, ON">ON</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="QTD1LED, OFF">OFF</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('QTD1LED, ON').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // Obtém os valores dos elementos #qrt e #led
        var status = document.getElementById('QTD1LED, ON').id;

        // Monta querystring para o POST com os valores dos elementos
        var params = '{' + status + '}';

        // Monta a requisição POST
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // Chama uma função quando o status do pedido for alterado
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                // Se o status for HTTP 200 (ok) e readyState==4 (DONE)
                alert('O servidor recebeu: ' + params);
            }
        }

        // Envia a requisição
        http.send(params);
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I use this code for HTTP POST Request from my index.html. How i can fix that?

Comment: You should also include the code that makes the request to the server.

Comment: @mscdex included!

Comment: But `recebido` is undefined == `blank page`.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting a `POST` request, but you haven't defined any `POST` route handlers. Add a route handler for the URL you are `POST`ing to and it should work fine.

Comment: how i can do that?

Comment: @LuizHenrique See for example: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html